# Temporary Tables (CTE) in MongoDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I know that common table expressions (CTE) a.k.a. "temporary named result sets" can be used in SQL to generate a temporary table, but can this be done in MongoDB? I want a document, but it's only for temporary use in my query.

**Can you create a temporary table in MongoDB without creating a new collection?**

For example, if I were to try to recreate the code below in Mongo...

### Example CTE Table in SQL:

| n | f1 | f2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 12 |
| 2 | 40 | 0.632 |
| 3 | 60 | 0.647 |

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE example (n, f1, f2) AS 
( SELECT 1, 20, 12
UNION ALL  SELECT 
n + 1,
n * 20, 
least(6*n, $globalVar * 100),
FROM example WHERE n < 3
) SELECT * FROM example
```

Comment: I know of `$graphLookup` stage, but I don't think this would be appropriate for my use case... I'm not needing to pass a collection

Comment: Might be better posted on sister site, https://DBA.StackExchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no general equivalent for CTE in MongoDB. However, for OP's example, it is possible to wrangle the output of `$range` to produce a similar effect.

```js
// whichever collection doesn't matter; as long as it has 1 document then it should be fine
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // jsut take 1 document
    "$limit": 1
  },
  {
    // use $range to generate iterator [1, 2, 3]
    "$addFields": {
      "rg": {
        "$range": [
          1,
          4
        ]
      },
      globalVar: 0.001
    }
  },
  {
    // do the mapping according to logic
    "$addFields": {
      "cte": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$rg",
          "as": "n",
          "in": {
            n: "$$n",
            f1: {
              "$multiply": [
                "$$n",
                20
              ]
            },
            f2: {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  $lt: [
                    {
                      "$multiply": [
                        "$$n",
                        6
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$multiply": [
                        "$globalVar",
                        100
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "then": {
                  "$multiply": [
                    "$$n",
                    6
                  ]
                },
                "else": {
                  "$multiply": [
                    "$globalVar",
                    100
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // wrangle back to expected form
    "$unwind": "$cte"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$cte"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/06pBbkioYWZ) for your reference.

Comment: What is the significance of `$$` in $$n? I've never come across a double dollar sign in Mongo before @ray

Comment: @cramos24 $$ is usually used for referencing variable. In our case, n is "declared" as a variable for our `$map`. You can check out [this official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) for more